# CodeIgniter form_dropdown selected value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form using CI's form_dropdown that pulls an array from DB....

```
$osValue = 'id = "osValue"';
echo form_dropdown('os', $os, '', $osValue);
```

which, when inspecting the element, is as follows in the user agent...

```
<select name="os" os>
<option value="1">Windows XP 32-bit</option>
<option value="2">Windows XP 64-bit</option>
<option value="3">Windows Vista 32-bit</option>
<option value="4">Windows Vista 64-bit</option>
<option value="5">Windows 7 32-bit</option>
<option value="6">Windows 7 64-bit</option>
<option value="7">Server 2003 32-bit</option>
<option value="8">Server 2003 64-bit</option>
<option value="9">Server 2008 32-bit</option>
<option value="10">Server 2008 64-bit</option>
<option value="11">Linux</option>
</select>
```

What I'm having trouble with is being able to pass ONLY the SELECTED value into a variable.

I get ALL options returned, when using

```
var os = $('#osValue').html();
```

or

```
var os = $('#osValue').text();
```

And, only the value (a numerical string passed in by the DB) is returned when using

```
var os = $('#osValue').val();
```

There has to be a small piece or two that I'm missing in order to have only the selected value returned.  Any/all advice or help would greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: First, `<select name="os" os>` seems defective, make sure `form_dropdown()` works properly. Second, what's wrong with `.val()`?

Comment: I'm unable to assign an ID, as this information is populated by CodeIgniter without an option for ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1) There is no ID on the select, yet you are querying for the id (you have an out-of-place "os" in there too; `<select name="os" os>` is not valid)

2) You aren't looking for which option has been selected

To fix, give the select an `id`:

```
<select name="os" id="os">
    <option value="1">Windows XP 32-bit</option>
    <option value="2">Windows XP 64-bit</option>
    <option value="3">Windows Vista 32-bit</option>
    <option value="4">Windows Vista 64-bit</option>
    <option value="5">Windows 7 32-bit</option>
    <option value="6">Windows 7 64-bit</option>
    <option value="7">Server 2003 32-bit</option>
    <option value="8">Server 2003 64-bit</option>
    <option value="9">Server 2008 32-bit</option>
    <option value="10">Server 2008 64-bit</option>
    <option value="11">Linux</option>
</select>
```

and query **that** from jQuery:

```
var osval = $('#os option:selected')
```

or, query by name:

```
var osval = $('[name="os"] option:selected')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Vmxd/

Comment: thank you for your help on this... just adding the "option:selected" to the jquery variable made this work flawlessly for me!